# Macbook Pro with OSX 10.9 does not boot

Tags: macos, boot, macbook-pro

My Macbook Pro has suddenly stopped booting. When booting normally, it just shows the gray screen with Apple logo and a spinning wheel, and hangs like this. When booting in Safe Mode (Shift key), it shows the progress bar, fills it up to about 25%, then the progress bar disappears, the spinning wheel shows up and it hangs.

In Single User Mode it boots OK and gives me a command prompt. As far as I can tell, the directory structure and user files are intact.

In verbose mode, the last message I see before it hangs is

```
Created virtif 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX p2p0
```

In Recovery mode it shows me Apple utilities. When I run the Disk Utility verifying and repairing the drives gives no errors.

Any suggestions what could be the issue? Any diagnostics I could run in Single User mode or in Repair mode from the command prompt?

Thanks in advance

Comment: create new user in single user mode and try with that.

Comment: I believe p2p0 is AirDrop. If you disable Wi-Fi, it might keep AirDrop from coming up. So try booting into Safe Mode, disabling Wi-Fi, and then see if your boot process gets any farther. If you can't disable Wi-Fi via the GUI in Safe Mode, you could boot into Single-User Mode by holding Cmd-S at boot, then follow the on-screen instructions to mount the boot drive read/write, then run `networksetup -setairportpower en1 off` (assuming your Wi-Fi is en1; if you're on a Retina MacBook Pro, it'll be en0; in some other cases, it may be a higher number)

Answer (score 0):

> created virtif 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX p2p0

Airport

create virtual interface ........point to point

I do not know what p2p set up you have but try to Enable that p2p or remove it in your settings.

That should allow the Verbose mode to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and did all the steps, provided in apple support site, but to no avail.
Then I boot with other installation and go to the 
/Volumes/OSX/Library/Extensions

(OSX is my faulty volume that holds my faulty OS.)
And there was a newly installed driver for huawei modems, which I delete, and reboot again, and it works.
Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get my MBP to boot.

1. Boot to safe mode
2. Start networking - when it prompts to mount HD, I accept
3. Resume Boot

Occasionally it hangs starting the network (step 2) - but usually it doesn't. 99% success rate for me about.

I have nVidia drivers installed and working.

Answer (score -1):

Samething happened to my 2013 retina Mac book pro. Thank god I had apple care on it. I took my Mac to apple and repair cost would have been around 1,200 Dollars. The problem was from the GPU. A logo booted up and with the spinning wheel, almost same with safe mode. They replaced the whole motherboard on my Mac.

Comment: This does not actually answer the author's question.  All this tell us is you had a problem, and you solved it, by taking it to Apple.